# Split line with specific string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, split

I have to take specific data from a file. I need to consider only lines that contains a specific string ("--TEST:") and takes the remaining characters

My file contains several lines like:

```
# = = = = =
# SETTING 
# = = = = = 
# install - ports
--TEST:ports_1              80
--TEST:ports_2              1024
INCLUDE: gvars/controller.cfg # temporary
```

I need to parse lines with "--TEST:" and take the remaining characters, like "ports_1" 
I'm reading the file using the code:

```
File.readlines(FILE_NAME).each do |line|
    .....
end
```

Then I'm trying to split each line by the string "--TEST:" and space "\s", but I think It is not the best and correct way

```
 line.split(--TEST:"\s/).each do |line_parsed|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

```
f = File.read(FILE_NAME)
f.scan(/^--TEST:(.*)$/) do |l|
  puts l
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works fine! With this code, only the lines that contain the string "--TEST" are taking into account. But, if I use l[0] I obtain all the line and l[1] NIL. How can I access to the string "port_1" for example?

Comment: `/^--TEST:(.*)$/` → `/^--TEST:(\S+)\s+(.*)$/`

Comment: Note that `read` differs from op `readlines` in that the whole file will be slurped into memory which might be bad for larger files.

Comment: Settings file are usually not GB-sized. Plus nothing would be wrong with the code if you’d surround it with the `readlines.each` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If your fields are always formatted like the sample try the regular expression:

```
re_test_string = /
  ^                        # start of line
  --TEST:                  # string
  (?<setting>[[:word:]]+)  # any word chars, setting
  [[:space:]]+             # any spaces
  (?<value>[[:word:]]+)    # any word chars, value
  $                        # end of line
/x
```

You can be more/less specific about the `setting` or `value` fields with different [character classes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes)

Then you can do something like pull all matching fields straight into an array.

```
settings = File.readlines(FILE_NAME).map do |line| 
  m = line.match( re_test_string )
  [ m[:setting], m[:value] ] if m
end.compact
```

or straight to a Hash in Ruby 2.1

```
settings.to_h
```